make negative values ​of the function disappear below the y-axis
I want the negative values ​​of the function, that is, those values ​​which are below the $|u|_{L^\infty(B)}$ axis to disappear or take value zero. I have tried some options which have been asked in the forum like this one: The "max" function on Tikz being annoying, help? But I have not got any desired result. Tried with max(.) but was not successful. If I change the value of the domain range on the left side, the shape of the function changes a lot. I need other solutions

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{fp}  
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  %lines%
  \draw[-stealth] (0, 0) -- (3, 0) node[right] {$\lambda$};
  \draw[-stealth] (0, 0) -- (0, 4.8) node[above] {$\|u\|_{L^\infty(B)}$};
  \draw[dotted] (1.55 , 0) -- (1.55, 6) node[above] {};
  %Nodes%
  \node at (1.5,-0.66) {$2(N-2)$};
  \node at (0 ,-0.66) {$\lambda^{*}$};  
  \node at (1.5,-1.3) {$3\leq N \leq 9$};  
  %Plots%
 \draw[scale=0.5, domain=-0.53:9.5, smooth, variable=\y, blue]  plot ( {  4*(exp(-0.4*\y))*sin(deg(4*pi*\y  - 0.44 )) + 3  }, {\y});  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center} 
\end{document}


Weclome. // May be you should change this option: domain=-0.53:9.5 ? Did you overlook that? Else: From which source did you copy the code?

Your code is missing some \ends for the center and the tikzpicture environment. Here, you could just do \clip (current bounding box.west|-0,0) rectangle (current bounding box.north east); before the plot. Otherwise, do you know of the pgfplots package?

Hello, the code is mine. I'm working in partial differential equations, the figure is from the  book Stable solutions of elliptic partial differential equations, Louis Dupaigne, in the page 45. I have already tried what you have mentioned. But if I change the value of the domain range on the left side, the shape of the function changes a lot. The best solution is to eliminate that little piece that I have pointed out. @MS-SPO

Ok. I suggest to add this information to your question. This way it’s easier to take into account. Or stated in reverse, it’s easy to overlook in comments.

Ok, turned out to be an artifact from having not enough values to plot, worsened by smoothing. See answer below https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/723860/245790 .

Finally , I have found a satisfactory solution. I removed the paramether smooth and used the clip command, and something else.
Thank to @MS-SPO and Qrrbrbirlbel .

Should I write the code that is correct in my question?

It’s better to post it as an answer: question ==problem, answer == solution.

Solution: domain=-0:9.5, samples=1000 ,   without smooth

What you see is an artifact from having not enough samples to plot. See the 4 plots below, using some x- and yshifts:

with 1000 samples both curves on the left are identical when adjusting domain
with too few (like in this extreme setting with 10 samples) it's unsstable as you describe
smoothing (deleted here) makes this artifact even worse

If your numerical solution is correct, the choice of the domain can't change the curves shape. Hints from a physics guy ;-)

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}  
%\usepackage{fp}  
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  %lines%
  \draw[-stealth] (0, 0) -- (3, 0) node[right] {$\lambda$};
  \draw[-stealth] (0, 0) -- (0, 4.8) node[above] {$\|u\|_{L^\infty(B)}$};
  \draw[dotted] (1.55 , 0) -- (1.55, 6) node[above] {};
  %Nodes%
  \node at (1.5,-0.66) {$2(N-2)$};
  \node at (0 ,-0.66) {$\lambda^{*}$};  
  \node at (1.5,-1.3) {$3\leq N \leq 9$};  


  %Plots%
 \draw[scale=0.5, domain=-0.53:9.5, samples=1000 , variable=\y, blue]  plot ( {  4*(exp(-0.4*\y))*sin(deg(4*pi*\y  - 0.44 )) + 3  }, {\y}) node[anchor=west,red]{1000 samples, -0.53:9.5}; 
  
 \draw[xshift=5cm,scale=0.5, domain=-0.53:9.5, samples=10 , variable=\y, blue]  plot ( {  4*(exp(-0.4*\y))*sin(deg(4*pi*\y  - 0.44 )) + 3  }, {\y}) node[anchor=west,red]{10 samples, -0.53:9.5};   
 
 
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-8cm]
 
 \draw[scale=0.5, domain=-0:9.5, samples=1000 , variable=\y, blue]  plot ( {  4*(exp(-0.4*\y))*sin(deg(4*pi*\y  - 0.44 )) + 3  }, {\y})  node[anchor=west,red]{1000 samples, 0:9.5};
  
 \draw[xshift=5cm,scale=0.5, domain=0:9.5, samples=10 , variable=\y, blue]  plot ( {  4*(exp(-0.4*\y))*sin(deg(4*pi*\y  - 0.44 )) + 3  }, {\y}) node[anchor=west,red]{10 samples, 0:9.5}; 
 
 \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center} 
\end{document}

P.S.: Viewed from communication theory, Nyquist criterium.
What you do with too few samples in numerical calculations is sampling more or less randomly the correct curve at a too low rate. See the Aliasing section here.
The handdrawn green lines shall visualze this a bit. By chance the "maximum" for the right curve WAS taken at some extreme value, while the ones before by chance were taken wrongly at too low values. Read the drawing from right to left.

